# SSRS dynamically shift columns on hide/show toggle

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to build an SSRS 2016 report. Is there a way to dynamically shift the columns in a table when you toggle with multiple groupings? I know I can change the visibility with a combination of the "InitialToggleState" and "ToggleItem" properties. However, doing this just leaves empty white space on the report and doesn't shift the columns.

Here is my current report:

[image]

and what it looks like when expanded:

[image]

Here is what I would like it to look like on load:

[image]

and what I would like it to look like when expanded:

[image]

**Edit:** To add further detail, field1-5 should only be shown when the parent has been toggled. When field1 below is collapsed, I would expect it to look like the image above again (field2 hidden).

[image]

**Edit2:** Would prefer not to add column groupings as suggested below as the data would then span across the headers. Some of my fields could return up to 8 values, I don't want to have 8 column headers in a grouping.

Comment: Will Field2-5 always be empty or unused or have no data in them?

Comment: @Mazhar Fields2-5 will always have data in them as users drill down through the data. The idea is on initial load Amount should be shown by Month. As the user drills into Month, field 1 is displayed with the sub amounts. As users drill into field1, field2 is displayed with the sub amounts and so on.

Comment: Add a column group and toggle the visibility with field1

Comment: @newGuy But then I would have data spanning across the headers which I don't want.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this?